# What is the value of a Word Legacy Text Form Field if nothing is entered?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, form-fields

I have a Word-based form that a user populates, and it includes legacy text form fields. When they are not filled in, these forms return what turns out in Excel (as in, in a worksheet) to be five spaces. If the user didn't enter anything, I want it to be blank. However, for the life of me, I can't figure out what these "five spaces" actually are in terms of characters. They are very clearly not five spaces, and I'm not aware of a five-space tab that can be called using Chr(). How can I find out what Word is actually returning from these unfilled form fields?

Comment: `For x=1 to Len(theValue): Debug.Print Asc(Mid(theValue, x, 1)): Next x` will tell you the character codes for each of the 5 characters. "theValue" is whatever you've read from the form field

Comment: You're a Godsend. I was trying to tackle the problem by thinking of it as a unit, not realizing that I could loop through each character in the value, however many there are. I will give this a try now.

Comment: @TimWilliams It's giving me 32 for each one. Very interesting.

Comment: Why did you think they were "very clearly not five spaces" ?

Comment: @TimWilliams I tried to exclude any unfilled fields by writing a statement like `If MyVal <> "     " Then...`, and it wasn't successful (the text in double quotes being five spaces). Any thoughts why that would be?

Comment: I would probably use something more like `myVal = Trim(myVal): If Len(myVal)>0 Then`  - that will take care of a case with all spaces, and has the added benefit of removing any "extra" spaces the user might have entered.

Comment: Yeah, I'm already using Trim elsewhere for some other responses and will do the same in this instance. Many thanks, Tim.

Comment: How is your formfield result actually ending up in Excel? Assuming your legacy formfield is actually the original, non-activeX type of formfield, what Word *displays* is 5 U+2002 en-space characters, which look like 'degree signs' which may account for the "they are clearly not spaces". If you copy those to an Excel cell (say A1), they look like spaces but if you inspect using a formula such as  =CODE(A1) you get 63 ("?"). For an unfilled field, the actual .Result of the field is a zero-length string.

Answer (score 1):

Each of the five characters is `Asc(32)`.